# Is this a correct use of std::forward?

Tags: c++, forward

I have a class named `core_table` that has two members:

```
std::list<std::pair<K, V>> data;
std::set<iterator, compare> gate; // gate contains pointers to the pairs!
```

All my insertions are based in this method. Is this a correct use of `std::forward?`

Everything works right and without problems. My understanding of `std::forward` is that it forwards the parameter as it is, thus taking advantage of overloaded operators and other templates that also make use of `std::forward`.

While inspecting the `std::list` implementation in Visual Studio, most of its methods, like push_back, emplace, emplace_back, etc, does make use of `std::forward`.

```
template <typename K, typename V>
core_table & insert(const_iterator cit, K && k, V && v) {
    auto const it = gate.find(k);
    if (it != gate.end()) {
        (*it)->second = std::forward<V>(v);
        return *this;
    }
    gate.emplace(data.emplace(cit, std::forward<K>(k), std::forward<V>(v)));
    return *this;
}
```

Other methods implemented with `insert`:

```
template <typename K, typename V>
core_table & push(K && k, V && v) {
    return insert(data.end(), std::forward<K>(k), std::forward<V>(v));
}

core_table & append(core_table const & ct) {
    for (auto const & e : ct) {
        push(e.first, e.second);
    }
    return *this;
}
```

Also, a bit off topic, how can I optimize the append method for `&&` parameters?

Comment: No, the move semantics get lost in the `append` function, `push` receives lvalues. You'd want `append` to receive `core_table&&`, then `for (auto&& e : ct) { push(std::move(e.first), std::move(e.second)); }` You cannot have `append` receive a `const` reference and then move out of it.

Comment: Yes, wherever you have used `std::forward`, you have used them correcty. However, you may want to add *another* overload  of `append` accepting `core_table &&`, so that `push` usage can be maximized.

Comment: But is the `insert` method correct? Do I just need to overload the append method for `core_table &&`?

Comment: So, everything is correctly and nicely implemented, everything I need to do is to overload append? :D

Comment: Yes. `insert` is perfect. even `push` is. Yes, just overload `append`.

Comment: I'm having one of those rare moments when I'm actually feeling proud of my job x)

Comment: @Nawaz, do I need to overload this constructor too? `core_table(std::initializer_list<value> const il) { for (auto const & e : il) { push(e.first, e.second); }}`, I tried with `std::move`, nothing happened, so I guess that I just leave it as it is?

Comment: @DagobertoPires: No. just remove the `const` (i.e accept argument by non-const value only), then `std::move` each elements in the `for` loop!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134936/discussion-between-nawaz-and-dagoberto-pires).